# Kafka producer config to send a message immediately

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am using Kafka producer 0.8.2 and I am trying to send a single message to the topic, in a way that the message is sent immediately. I have a console consumer to observe if the message arrives. I notice that the message is not sent immediately, unless of course I run producer.close(), immediately after sending, which isn't what I would like to do.

What is the correct producer configuration setting to target this? I'm using the following (I'm aware that it looks like a mess of different configurations/versions, but I simply cannot find something that's working as I would expect in the documentation):

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokersStr);
props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, "3");
props.put("producer.type", "sync");
props.put("batch.num.messages", "1");
props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
props.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "none");
props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 1);
props.put(ProducerConfig.BLOCK_ON_BUFFER_FULL_CONFIG, true);
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, which seems reasonable, and involves running get() on the Future returned by the Producer's send() command. I changed the send command from:

```
producer.send(record);
```

to the following:

```
producer.send(record).get();
```

It would be nice to hear from the more experienced Kafka users if there are any issues with that approach? Also, I would be interested to learn if there is a configuration setting for the Producer to achieve the same thing (that is, send a single message immediately without running get() of the Future).

Comment: Yes I really want to know about if there are any configs for achieving this without running get() as it is useful in some test scenarios

Answer (score -1):

Old post but I have struggled way to much to miss a post here.

I stumbled upon the same behavior trying to run the Kafka examples and this `.get()` was the only thing that got the messages to Kafka. [The Javadoc for `KafkaProducer.send(…)`](https://kafka.apache.org/082/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#send%28org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord%29) states this method is asynchronous. On my test code, the message was thus sent to Kafka while my code continued to run and actually just got to the end of the run and terminated before the message was actually sent inside the `Future`.

So this `.get()` just blocks on the `Future` until it is realized. This actually removes the benefits of the `Future`. A cleaner way to do it could be to wait a bit with a `Thread.sleep(…)` right after the `.send(…)` (depends on your use case).

Comment: How is a sleep better?  Now instead of waiting till the Future to complete, you have some random wait.  If you have to wait till it finishes, the get() is the simpler approach.